Select features based on a list of values in a .csv file
I want to extract about 5000 features from a vector layer with over 1 million features. Each feature has a unique code in a field named "KAT". I have a .csv file that contains all the codes I want to select. I have no python experience. I could not figure out how to read in the .csv file directly so I figured, I just paste all the values in the python script. I tried to modify one answer from this question: Selecting multiple features by ID-attribute from list using PyQGIS
Small example I tried.
id_list = ["86502:002:0029",
"49301:003:0432",
"69701:005:0276",
"91804:003:0209",
"86502:002:0760"]

for i in id_list:
    layer.selectByExpression("\"KAT\" = {}".format(i), QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)

The code runs few seconds without error messages but nothing gets selected.
I know the codes do exist. When using a code in the "select features" form it will get selected.
Being able to read values directly from the file would be nice but not critical.

You should do one query, with the IN SQL operator (WHERE KAT IN ('{:s}'".format("','".join(id_list)))

Try one of the other suggestions - without a loop: layer.selectByExpression("KAT in {}".format(tuple(id_list)))

Some databases (cough Oracle) have issues with large IN lists, in which case, you can break the list into chunks of 200. You should certainly have an index on the queried field.

@Aquamarine Ok thanks that worked
